# grep to replace strings in files iteratively on all subfolders, excluding some branches

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find out how to replace specific strings on all file of a directory and all the subfolders iteratively BUT excluding some subfoldes AND some file extensions. All at the same time.

I've seen some examples of how to replace strings iteratively but cannot make it to have all this process in one single command.

Any one knows? :)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/dir \
-type f
-path /path/to/dir/to/exclude -prune -o\
-not -name '*.conf'\
-exec sed -i 's/remove/replace/g' {} \;
```

- Searches `/path/to/dir`
- Excludes `/path/to/dir/to/exclude`
- Excludes `*.conf` files
- Replaces `remove` with `replace` in all other files

Comment: the subfolder is still included, for example I type the followoing: find ./ -type f -path ./test_folder1/sub_test_folder2/ -prune -o -not -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/hellp/bye/g' {} \;